# Can't see button in MoviePlayer if using FullScreen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

The following is the code I used to play a movie:

```
playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

float screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
float screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
[playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

//---play movie---
player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[player setFullscreen:TRUE];
[player play];

skipButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[skipButton setTitle:@"Skip" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
skipButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50);

[skipButton setCenter:CGPointMake(screenWidth - 30 - skipButton.frame.size.width, 100)];
[skipButton addTarget:self action:@selector(skipMovie) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:skipButton];
```

But, I have some issue with these on iPad1. If I did not use the `setFullScreen` method, the movie didn't play in FullScreen mode, even if I set the Rect (1024x768). But if I set these, the movie does play in FullScreen, but my @skipButton is not visible.

If i use:

```
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
```

after

```
[player play];
```

the first issue happened. The code works properly in iPad2, even without `setFullScreen`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
[playerViewController.view bringSubviewToFront: skipButton]
```

doesn't make any change!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this issue by using this method

```
[playerViewController.view bringSubviewToFront: skipButton];
```

Please **call** this **function** only **after** your **movie player loads the movie**.